# os.system complains about round brackets

Tags: python, awk, paste, os.system

I am trying to include this line in a python script.

```
!#/bin/bash/env python

import os

os.system("paste <(awk '!/^($|[:space:]*#)/{print $0}' file1) <(awk '!/^($|[:space:]*#)/{print $0} file2) > out_file")
```

The command is perfectly fine when run from bash directly. However, inside the script, I get:

```
sh: -c: line0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The problem persists when using simply:

```
os.system("paste <(cat file1) > output_file")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like your default shell is `sh`, not `bash`. And both of your command lines are invalid with `sh`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: He's not using `subprocess`, he's using `os.system`. Which, on Unix systems, just calls the libc function `system`, which uses… well, that's up to your OS, and we don't know what OS the OP is using.

Comment: @abarnert: right, indeed; my mistake. I'll point to [`man system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) instead then, which states it uses `/bin/sh -c`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Did the OP say he's using linux somewhere, or are you just assuming that everyone who tries to use `system` is on linux?

Comment: @abarnert: I am assuming it's a POSIX system, since `sh` and `bash` are installed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: POSIX only requires a shell that acts as if it were `sh` when given a valid `sh` command (which means it could extend `sh` in ways that don't prevent running valid `sh` commands). Some platforms (like cygwin) use `bash` with the right flags as `sh`, but use different flags as `sh` vs. as `system`. (For that matter, it also allows, but "discourages", following the `SHELL` env variable—because at least one commercial UNIX did so.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The command is perfectly fine when run from bash directly. However, inside the script, I get:

```
sh: -c: line0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

That's because inside the script, you're running the command with `sh` rather than `bash`. Both this command, and the simpler one, use `bash`-specific features. Try running an `sh` shell and typing the same lines, and you'll get the same error.

The [os.system](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) call doesn't document what shell it uses, because it's:

> implemented by calling the Standard C function `system()`

On most Unix-like systems, this calls `sh`. You probably shouldn't rely on that… but you *definitely* shouldn't rely on it calling `bash`!

If you want to run `bash` commands, use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) module, and run `bash` explicitly:

```
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', 'paste <(cat file1) > output_file'])
```

You could, I suppose, try to get the quoting right to run `bash` as a subshell within the shell `system` uses… but why bother?

This is one of the many reasons that the documentation repeatedly tells you that you should consider using `subprocess` instead of `os.system`.

Comment: And you should add that in order to run the command in `bash` you can use subprocess, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4256153/418609).

Comment: @adrianp: That answer doesn't show how to use `bash` explicitly; it shows how to run the `cwm` command without using a shell, which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Kill two birds with one `awk` script:

```
awk -v DELIM=' ' '!/^($|[[:space:]]*#)/{a[FNR]=a[FNR]DELIM$0}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print substr(a[i],2)}' file1 file2
```

This eliminates the need for process substitution and is therefor `sh` compliant.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the situation is a bit more complicated: I don't specify the number of files directly, but rather they are arguments of the script, e.g. script.py file1 file2 file3 ... In other words: I have no idea on how to extend your example to N files. Do I have to do it a couple at a time? file1+file2=part1 part1+file3=part2 partN-1+fileN=final?

Comment: @astabada You would just parse the list of files after the script `file1 file2 ... fileN` . Calling `awk` multiple times (once per file) is the wrong approach when a single script can handle it. Subsequently this eliminates your original problem.

Comment: ok, it works... One further (and last, hopefully) question. Do you know of any comprehensive place where to look to understand the command? man awk does not seem sufficient.

Comment: Read effective awk programming here is a line http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/